# Cannot retrieve the stats of my docker containers using Docker APIs

Tags: docker, docker-api

I have several containers that are running on my Centos7 VM and I would like to retrieve their CPU and Memory usage using the following command:

```
echo -e "GET /containers/(container_name)/stats HTTP/1.0\r\n" | \
  nc -U /var/run/docker.sock
```

However, I just receive the following message without any statistics:

> HTTP/1.0 200 OK
>
> Server: Docker/1.10.3 (linux)
>
> Date: Sun, 22 Jan 2017 15:53:49 GMT
>
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
>
> The "containers/(container_name)/top" command works fine.

Can you please help me to understand why I don't receive this container's statistics?

Comment: Are you sure that the `/stats` endpoint is supported in the version of Docker you're running?  It looks like you have 1.10.3, which isn't current.

Comment: You have right, this is the docker version that I use. Is there some way to retrieve the CPU and Memory usage of the containers in this version? Thanks.

Comment: You could simply upgrade the version of docker that you're running. Docker provides packages for centos.

Answer (score 0):

**Command to use get the stats of the container:**

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:6000/containers/<container_id>/stats
```

The stats will be displayed for every second.

**Stats can be fetched only for running containers.**

Refer this :

[how to configure docker daemon port.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43699368/configure-docker-daemon-port-to-enable-docker-apis/43713435#43713435)