# Configure Docker daemon port to enable Docker APIs

Tags: docker

I was trying to configure the **Docker daemon port** as mentioned in **[a link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/#configure-the-docker-daemon)**:

```
cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
"debug": "true",
"hosts": "tcp://127.0.0.1:5000"
}

# Service docker status
docker stop/waiting
# service docker start
start: Job failed to start

Docker version: 17.04
```

I enabled the **debug logs** to check the issue for starting the Docker service and got to know from logs at `/var/log/upstart/docker.log`:

```
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type bool
```

What is **causing the issue for the Docker container to start?** Is anything wrong in the configuration file `daemon.json`?

The issues after suggested changes:

```
cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
"debug": true,
"hosts": "tcp://127.0.0.1:5000"
}
```

ERROR:

```
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type []string
```

So I changed it to:

```
cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
"debug": true,
"hosts": ["tcp://127.0.0.1:5000"]
}
```

And the debug log:

```
# cat /var/log/upstart/docker.log
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
time="2017-04-29T21:49:39.082025019+05:30" level=warning msg="[!] DON'T BIND ON ANY IP ADDRESS WITHOUT setting --tlsverify IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING [!]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:39.087462580+05:30" level=debug msg="Listener created for HTTP on tcp (127.0.0.1:5000)"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:39.091623380+05:30" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 28412"
DEBU[0000] containerd: read past events                  count=0
DEBU[0000] containerd: supervisor running                cpus=1 memory=3953 runtime=docker-runc runtimeArgs=[] stateDir="/var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd"
DEBU[0000] containerd: grpc api on /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
time="2017-04-29T21:49:39.594179140+05:30" level=debug msg="libcontainerd: containerd health check returned error: rpc error: code = 14 desc = grpc: the connection is unavailable"
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.093473005+05:30" level=debug msg="libcontainerd: containerd health check returned error: rpc error: code = 14 desc = grpc: the connection is unavailable"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.103148602+05:30" level=debug msg="Using default logging driver json-file"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.104791557+05:30" level=debug msg="Golang's threads limit set to 56610"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.120505279+05:30" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: aufs"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.121399341+05:30" level=debug msg="Using graph driver aufs"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.127259410+05:30" level=debug msg="Max Concurrent Downloads: 3"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.127366059+05:30" level=debug msg="Max Concurrent Uploads: 5"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.139747219+05:30" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.140011955+05:30" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap memory limit"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.140100084+05:30" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.140216600+05:30" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.140342372+05:30" level=warning msg="mountpoint for pids not found"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.140594173+05:30" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.141501935+05:30" level=debug msg="Loaded container 0102006e71695802c5f21edbb9dc4776d4c291d28c8db21fbc30144c7ee5ac58"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.142853279+05:30" level=debug msg="Loaded container 01c63f92586b3e792b0bcf5c9081126c71ce816ad4d38031e2bd2019ba536461"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.143269945+05:30" level=debug msg="Loaded container 0523a71851447b55b18fe3c8e9ac904837bd5062cc237f7cb507a9e4e3cda410"

   ** REMOVED THE CONTAINERS LOADING INFO **

time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.165085939+05:30" level=debug msg="Loaded container ff01985e70fe0d14210c88b768b2ea521d4521d376e5df0e90895533e577b92e"
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.289009591+05:30" level=debug msg="Option Experimental: false"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.289131532+05:30" level=debug msg="Option DefaultDriver: bridge"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.289205442+05:30" level=debug msg="Option DefaultNetwork: bridge"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.294576340+05:30" level=info msg="Firewalld running: false"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.297766934+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -D PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.299341976+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -D OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL ! --dst 127.0.0.0/8 -j DOCKER]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.301053126+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -D OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.302616266+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -D PREROUTING]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.304229207+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -D OUTPUT]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.305711736+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -F DOCKER]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.307077262+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -X DOCKER]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.308535928+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -F DOCKER]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.309902224+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -X DOCKER]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.311637703+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -F DOCKER-ISOLATION]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.313500303+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -X DOCKER-ISOLATION]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.315093100+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -n -L DOCKER]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.316612016+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -N DOCKER]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.318047831+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -n -L DOCKER]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.319496142+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -n -L DOCKER-ISOLATION]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.320978680+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.322453938+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -I DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.327870386+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.329395686+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.330870634+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -I DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.332401751+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -D FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j DROP]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.333933984+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.335444643+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.337019261+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.338699953+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.340319708+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER ! --dst 127.0.0.0/8]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.342595449+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -A OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER ! --dst 127.0.0.0/8]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.344321469+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.345835836+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.347371940+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.348970025+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.350514996+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION]"
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.354889362+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -D FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.356534823+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -I FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.358137686+05:30" level=debug msg="Network (cdd354f) restored"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.369466443+05:30" level=debug msg="Allocating IPv4 pools for network bridge (cdd354f255bdc31986952e845957b04baa477ed7362b4b3b7ed606c31850d68a)"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.369595546+05:30" level=debug msg="RequestPool(LocalDefault, 172.17.0.0/16, , map[], false)"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.369730759+05:30" level=debug msg="RequestAddress(LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16, 172.17.0.1, map[RequestAddressType:com.docker.network.gateway])"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.371387634+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.373112693+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.374880382+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.376591245+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -D DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.378326734+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.380015825+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -D FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.381638134+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.383258380+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -D FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.384970620+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.386558723+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.388624059+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -D FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.390622271+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.392615245+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.394577019+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -D FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.398027079+05:30" level=debug msg="releasing IPv4 pools from network bridge (cdd354f255bdc31986952e845957b04baa477ed7362b4b3b7ed606c31850d68a)"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.398174850+05:30" level=debug msg="ReleaseAddress(LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16, 172.17.0.1)"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.398258452+05:30" level=debug msg="ReleasePool(LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16)"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.400734572+05:30" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.400866715+05:30" level=debug msg="Allocating IPv4 pools for network bridge (f729ff1f8c660b13bc5567d8a30cde03698b4df6a4d0fdbced201a7452fbf0f0)"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.400921339+05:30" level=debug msg="RequestPool(LocalDefault, 172.17.0.0/16, , map[], false)"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.400984209+05:30" level=debug msg="RequestAddress(LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16, 172.17.0.1, map[RequestAddressType:com.docker.network.gateway])"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.401150859+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.402745792+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.404360129+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.405955436+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -I DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.407494814+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -D FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j DROP]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.409144994+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.410904462+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -I FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.412607157+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.414338440+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -I FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.415979126+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.417726152+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.419367167+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER ! --dst 127.0.0.0/8]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.421122358+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER ! --dst 127.0.0.0/8]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.422856895+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.424550825+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -I FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.426107430+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.427991143+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -I FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.429645428+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.431266204+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -D FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION]"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.432879578+05:30" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -I FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION]"
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.500868327+05:30" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.519559145+05:30" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.519681055+05:30" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=4845c56 graphdriver=aufs version=17.04.0-ce
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.519845570+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering routers"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.519892553+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/checkpoints"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.520055568+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/checkpoints"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.520182547+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering DELETE, /containers/{name}/checkpoints/{checkpoint}"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.520360059+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering HEAD, /containers/{name:.*}/archive"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.520479299+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /containers/json"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.520574487+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/export"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.520683367+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/changes"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.520823502+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/json"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.520936230+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/top"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.521036359+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/logs"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.521146161+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/stats"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.521313628+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/attach/ws"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.521421473+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /exec/{id:.*}/json"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.521516457+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/archive"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.521620140+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/create"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.521745578+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/kill"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.521860358+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/pause"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.521964539+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/unpause"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.522067959+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/restart"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.522167019+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/start"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.522308397+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/stop"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.522414580+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/wait"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.522514975+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/resize"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.522619004+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/attach"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.522787092+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/copy"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.522894615+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/exec"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.523003923+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /exec/{name:.*}/start"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.523107351+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /exec/{name:.*}/resize"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.523264006+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/rename"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.523376319+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/update"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.523513783+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/prune"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.523612647+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering PUT, /containers/{name:.*}/archive"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.523828369+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering DELETE, /containers/{name:.*}"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.523955417+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /images/json"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.524052679+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /images/search"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.524136911+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /images/get"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.524247693+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /images/{name:.*}/get"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.524372724+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /images/{name:.*}/history"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.524487290+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /images/{name:.*}/json"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.524597100+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /commit"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.524677000+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /images/load"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.524786382+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /images/create"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.524879353+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /images/{name:.*}/push"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.524991660+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /images/{name:.*}/tag"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.525104838+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /images/prune"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.525226759+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering DELETE, /images/{name:.*}"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.525335549+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering OPTIONS, /{anyroute:.*}"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.525435401+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /_ping"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.525511894+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /events"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.525591165+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /info"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.525669340+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /version"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.525814930+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /system/df"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.525897277+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /auth"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.525970337+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /volumes"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.526057298+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /volumes/{name:.*}"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.526163662+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /volumes/create"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.526353639+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /volumes/prune"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.526442022+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering DELETE, /volumes/{name:.*}"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.526546136+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /build"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.526623235+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /swarm/init"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.526737579+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /swarm/join"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.526819211+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /swarm/leave"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.526899446+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /swarm"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.526980042+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /swarm/unlockkey"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.527069861+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /swarm/update"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.527158981+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /swarm/unlock"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.527342136+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /services"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.527474641+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /services/{id}"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.527609687+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /services/create"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.527758523+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /services/{id}/update"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.527871673+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering DELETE, /services/{id}"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.527970912+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /services/{id}/logs"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.528072255+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /nodes"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.528151801+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /nodes/{id}"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.528287417+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering DELETE, /nodes/{id}"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.528390020+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /nodes/{id}/update"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.528493003+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /tasks"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.528572710+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /tasks/{id}"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.528689980+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /secrets"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.528796825+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /secrets/create"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.528884054+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering DELETE, /secrets/{id}"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.528992153+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /secrets/{id}"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.529100356+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /secrets/{id}/update"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.529246933+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /plugins"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.529333481+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /plugins/{name:.*}/json"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.529433799+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /plugins/privileges"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.529532846+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering DELETE, /plugins/{name:.*}"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.529640124+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /plugins/{name:.*}/enable"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.529776734+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /plugins/{name:.*}/disable"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.529884453+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /plugins/pull"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.529979852+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /plugins/{name:.*}/push"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.530083752+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /plugins/{name:.*}/upgrade"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.530177424+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /plugins/{name:.*}/set"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.530348200+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /plugins/create"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.530432901+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /networks"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.530518503+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /networks/"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.530599687+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /networks/{id:.+}"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.530751284+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /networks/create"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.530853286+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /networks/{id:.*}/connect"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.530960464+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /networks/{id:.*}/disconnect"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.531072661+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /networks/prune"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.531154778+05:30" level=debug msg="Registering DELETE, /networks/{id:.*}"
time="2017-04-29T21:49:40.531568754+05:30" level=info msg="API listen on 127.0.0.1:5000"
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
.....
```

Now the **Docker container is waiting for an infinite period. What is causing this issue?**

**Able to start the same with dockerd manually:**

```
#dockerd -H tcp://127.0.0.1:5000 &
[1] 31661
root@labadmin-VirtualBox:/etc/docker# WARN[0000] [!] DON'T BIND ON ANY IP ADDRESS WITHOUT setting --tlsverify IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING [!]
INFO[0000] libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 31665
WARN[0000] containerd: low RLIMIT_NOFILE changing to max  current=1024 max=4096
INFO[0001] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver: aufs
INFO[0001] Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds
WARN[0001] Your kernel does not support swap memory limit
WARN[0001] Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period
WARN[0001] Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime
WARN[0001] mountpoint for pids not found
INFO[0001] Loading containers: start.
INFO[0001] Firewalld running: false
INFO[0001] Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address
INFO[0001] Loading containers: done.
INFO[0001] Daemon has completed initialization
INFO[0001] Docker daemon                                 commit=4845c56 graphdriver=aufs version=17.04.0-ce
INFO[0001] API listen on 127.0.0.1:5000

# netstat -tunlp | grep -i 5000
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31661/dockerd
```

Comment: Do you have `DOCKER_OPTS` set in the environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an addition to the answer provided by [Dan Lowe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2449905/dan-lowe).

There are two ways in configuring the Docker daemon port:

1. Configuring at **/etc/default/docker** file:

   ```
   DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://127.0.0.1:5000 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
   ```
2. Configuring at **/etc/docker/daemon.json**:

   ```
   {
   "debug": true,
   "hosts": ["tcp://127.0.0.1:5000", "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"]
   }
   ```

Restart the Docker service after configuring the port.

If the Docker default socket is not configured, the similar issue mentioned in the question may occur, i.e., **Docker will wait for an infinite period**.

Note: But don't configure in ***both*** the configuration files. The following error may occur:

```
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: the following directives are specified both as a flag and in the configuration file: hosts: (from flag: [tcp://127.0.0.1:5000 unix:///var/run/docker.sock], from file: tcp://127.0.0.1:5000)
```

The reason for adding both the **user port[ tcp://127.0.0.1:5000]** and **default Docker socket[unix:///var/run/docker.sock]** is that the user port enables the access to the **Docker APIs** whereas the default socket enables the CLI. In case the default port[unix:///var/run/docker.sock] is not mentioned in the `/etc/default/docker` file the following error may occur:

```
# docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

This error is not because that the Docker container is not running, but because the default Docker socket is not enabled.

This is applicable for Docker version 17.04, and it may vary with different versions of Docker.

Comment: I get the error: "hosts" cannot be used in Docker Desktop

Comment: may I know are you running in windows or linux, as this solution works for linux.

Comment: I'm on OSX High Sierra

Comment: this was verified in Ubuntu 14.04, might need some modifications in MAC.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is valid.

```
"debug": "true",
```

`"true"` is a string, but the expected type here is boolean. Try this instead:

```
"debug": true,
```

This is consistent with the error you saw,

> cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type bool

`hosts` appears to expect an array. Try this:

```
"hosts": ["tcp://127.0.0.1:5000"]
```

Comment: Even the link that OP refers to has it as a bool :/ :p

Comment: @johnharris85 Sure, but it doesn't make a point of saying so, and if you don't know how JSON works, it's not necessarily obvious there's a difference.

Comment: @DanLowe: changed as you have suggested, now a different error:unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type []string

Comment: tried with updated answer, now the docker is waiting infinitely : Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock...., no further logs..