# How to build an Image using Docker API?

Tags: docker, docker-api

I am trying to build a **docker Image using the APIs** mentioned in the [official link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/#images).

But I am unable to get what the document says:
Example request:

```
POST /v1.24/build HTTP/1.1


{{ TAR STREAM }}
```

There are few things which are confusing me,

1) Where to mention the **path for the Dockerfile**?

2) "The archive must include a build instructions file, typically called Dockerfile at the archive’s root." This statement from docker docs, the confusion here is **what is archive's root**?

3) What is the **command in detail for building an Image**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, able to **build an image through Docker API**.

Sample Dockerfile:

```
# cat Dockerfile

FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN mkdir demo
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install vim
```

Create a tar file which includes your Dockerfile.

```
# tar -cvf Dockerfile.tar.gz Dockerfile
```

Execute the API as below and for more options, refer [this.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.28/#operation/ImageBuild)

```
# curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/tar" --data-binary '@Dockerfile.tar.gz' http://127.0.0.1:5000/build?t=build_test

* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> POST /build?t=build_test HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:application/tar
> Content-Length: 10240
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Api-Version: 1.28
< Content-Type: application/json
< Docker-Experimental: false
< Ostype: linux
* Server Docker/17.04.0-ce (linux) is not blacklisted
< Server: Docker/17.04.0-ce (linux)
< Date: Mon, 01 May 2017 09:56:54 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
{"stream":"Step 1/4 : FROM ubuntu:14.04\n"}
{"stream":" ---\u003e 302fa07d8117\n"}
{"stream":"Step 2/4 : RUN mkdir demo\n"}
{"stream":" ---\u003e Running in 5941f911099e\n"}
{"stream":" ---\u003e bccbffdd776a\n"}
{"stream":"Removing intermediate container 5941f911099e\n"}
{"stream":"Step 3/4 : RUN apt-get update\n"}
{"stream":" ---\u003e Running in 7aefd190a165\n"}
{"stream":"Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease\n"}
{"stream":"Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]\n"}
{"stream":"Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease [65.9 kB]\n"}
{"stream":"Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg [933 B]\n"}
{"stream":"Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release [58.5 kB]\n"}
{"stream":"Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [491 kB]\n"}
{"stream":"Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [6467 B]\n"}
{"stream":"Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [226 kB]\n"}

.......    

{"stream":"Fetched 22.5 MB in 1min 40s (224 kB/s)\nReading package lists..."}
{"stream":"\n"}
{"stream":" ---\u003e ff06741dea7e\n"}
{"stream":"Removing intermediate container 7aefd190a165\n"}
{"stream":"Step 4/4 : RUN apt-get -y install vim\n"}
{"stream":" ---\u003e Running in e9ddad5a4695\n"}
{"stream":"Reading package lists..."}
{"stream":"\n"}
{"stream":"Building dependency tree..."}
{"stream":"\nReading state information...\n"}
{"stream":"The following extra packages will be installed:\n  libgpm2 libpython2.7 libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib vim-runtime\n"}
{"stream":"Suggested packages:\n  gpm ctags vim-doc vim-scripts\n"}
{"stream":"The following NEW packages will be installed:\n  libgpm2 libpython2.7 libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib vim\n  vim-runtime\n"}
{"stream":"0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.\nNeed to get 9074 kB of archives.\nAfter this operation, 42.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.\nGet:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libgpm2 amd64 1.20.4-6.1 [16.5 kB]\n"}
 .......
{"stream":"Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.11) ...\n"}
{"stream":" ---\u003e b1736dd9b698\n"}
{"stream":"Removing intermediate container e9ddad5a4695\n"}
{"stream":"Successfully built b1736dd9b698\n"}
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

Check the docker images after the image is successfully built.

```
# docker images
REPOSITORY                       TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
build_test                       latest              b1736dd9b698        8 seconds ago       254MB
```

Removed some of the output which is not necessary.

To **configure docker daemon port** , refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43699368/unable-to-start-docker-after-configuring-daemon-json/43713435#43713435)

Comment: The mentioned Dockerfile is super simple. It doesn't require copying the source code, scripts executions, etc. I have issues with **that** kind of Dockerfile. The suggested approach doesn't work when I pack the whole project into TAR and then pass it to Docker API.