# Is it possible to create Dockerfile from the container/image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a container up and running. Is it a way to generate Dockerfile from the running container or from its image? Please advice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a new docker image from a running container on Amazon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027873/how-to-create-a-new-docker-image-from-a-running-container-on-amazon)

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Your best bet would be to commit the container (with whatever changes you made) to make an image that could serve as the base image for your desired image's Dockerfile.