# Deploy existing docker container on different machine

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I am new to using docker.

I have pulled an image for Jenkins from the docker repository and made some changes in the Jenkins server that has been deployed via docker.

Currently this container is running on my machine,and I want run this Jenkins image with my changes on a seperate machine as well.

Is it possible to push my snapshot of the Jenkins images to some repo and then pull it on a different machine and run it there as well?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should really make your image by creating a Dockerfile that makes the changes you need. That way, you can easily do it again when an updated Jenkins image comes out.

That being said, it is possible to create an image from a running container using

```
docker commit [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]
```

So if your container is called `mycontainer`, your repository is `myrepository` and you want to call the image `myjenkins`, you'd do

```
docker commit mycontainer myrepository/myjenkins:latest
```

and then push it to the repository using

```
docker push myrepository/myjenkins:latest
```

Then, on your other machine, you can pull it and run it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`docker commit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027873/how-to-create-a-new-docker-image-from-a-running-container-on-amazon) to generate a new image that includes any modifications made in the container. You can then push that image like normal.

Comment: This is almost never a best practice.  In addition to creating a non-reproducible image, committing an image doesn't include any data that might be stored in Docker volumes; if you've manually configured Jenkins by editing configuration files, and those files are in named or anonymous volumes, committing won't preserve the changes.