# `docker run` on a remote host

Tags: linux, docker

is it possible (using the `docker` command or the `docker-py` API directly) to start a container from a remote host?

Lets assume I have two machines that have different architectures:
- A is an `x86` machine
- B is an `ARM` machine

I would like to run a container on the B machine using my A machine. At first, I thought it was possible using this command:

```
[A]$> DOCKER_HOST=$MACHINE_B_IP:$MACHIN_B_PORT docker run hello-from-B
```

But this command actually pulls the image `hello-from-B` and tries to run it on the machine A which ends up on some `exec format error` cause obviously you can't run images that are specific to `ARM` to an `x86` machine.

Communication between machine A and B is working well. I can run commands like `images` or `ps` and it gives me the expected results:

```
[A]$> DOCKER_HOST=$MACHINE_B_IP:$MACHIN_B_PORT docker images
REPOSITORY                TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
hello-from-B              <none>              fd5059044831        13 hours ago        1.26GB
```

I've heard about `docker-machine` and haven't tried it yet, but from my understanding, this won't solve my problem.

Is there any way to achieve that using `docker` directly. A workaround might be to using `ssh` to connect to the remote host and use the `docker` client directly from the remote host, but I'd like to avoid this solution as much as possible.

Thanks in advance,

---

TL;DR;

How can `DOCKER_HOST=... docker run something` runs `something` on the `DOCKER_HOST` rather than running it on my local machine.

Comment: Did you try to use the `-H` flag? Like `docker -H tcp://[host]:[port][path] run hello-from-B`?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww my bad, you're totally right. :)

Comment: `docker -H ssh://me@server run -it --rm busybox` is possible with docker 18.09. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53252524/6309)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your targeted machine B could be created on one of [these platform](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/) then, I guess, `docker-machine` would serve your needs.

You would create your machine using `docker-machine create --driver <..driver setup..> MACHINE_B` then you activate it using `eval $(docker-machine env MACHINE_B)`.

`docker-machine env MACHINE_B`  will print out some export statements:

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://...."
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/..."
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="MACHINE_B"
```

Once your machine is active, you can use the `docker` command as you would locally to act remotely **on MACHINE_B**.

Comment: It seems that `generic` driver might be one solution. I've also heard about `none` driver but can't really find documentation about this one. Anyway, `docker-machine` is probably what I'm looking for, I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Good Luck with that, I haven't used driver `none` myself, but I found [here](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4045) an [article](https://www.boerngen-schmidt.de/2017/05/connect-to-a-remote-docker-host-with-docker-machine-using-tls-certificates/) about it.

Comment: It seems that `docker-machine` isn't solving my problem. It still ends up with an: `exec format error`. For some reason, it tries to execute my container (which is based on `aarch64` arch) on my `x86_64` machine). Maybe that's because of the driver and other driver works as expected. Also.. I'm trying to use `docker` in non-conventional way. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Actually I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to start the `hello-world` image which is built by default for `x86` machine. So it might works... I'll keep you in touch.

Comment: Everything works fine with `docker-machine`. At first point, I was only using `DOCKER_HOST` which should also work as expected. I wasn't paying attention to the images I tried to run. Also, as a side note, `docker-machine` requires TLS (or at least, older versions), I've tried a bunch of `tlsnoverify` blahblah for testing purposes but none were working. Now that I've set up the whole TLS environment, I can use it without any trouble. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that and happy that I could help

Comment: Short but very clear explanation, helps understand the *how* for `docker-machine use`.

Answer (score 41):

Check if the latest docker 18.09 includes that feature.
See [docker/cli PR 1014](https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/1014)

> ### Added support for SSH connection. e.g. `docker -H ssh://me@server`
>
> - The cli should accept `ssh://me@server` for `DOCKER_HOST` and `-H`. Using that would execute ssh with the passed config.
> - The ssh command would call a hidden command on the docker CLI binary on the remote side. For example, docker dial-stdio.
>
> This command will make a connection to the local `DOCKER_HOST` variable (almost always the default local socket) and forward that connection on the commands stdio.
>   Even though this command is supposed to run locally to the `dockerd` binary, we think that it is an invalid configuration for this feature to remove the local `docker` binary so we can rely on it always being present.
>
> How to verify it
>
> ```
> docker -H ssh://me@server run -it --rm busybox
> ```

The reaction so far:

> From ops and sysadmins everywhere, we thank you for this fantastic and unexpected feature.
>   I'm hoping this will seriously cut down the number of times I see people opening `dockerd` TCP w/o TLS and just opt for SSH endpoints for remote mgmt.

Comment: and I thank you for posting this answer - worked like a charm!

Answer (score 5):

This article explains the concept very well: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#bind-docker-to-another-hostport-or-a-unix-socket

Considering the huge warning on the page, I suggest you resort to using a secure connection via SSH ie. `ssh user@host 'docker run hello-from-B'`

> ***Warning: Changing the default docker daemon binding to a TCP port or Unix docker user group will increase your security risks by
>   allowing non-root users to gain root access on the host. Make sure you
>   control access to docker. If you are binding to a TCP port, anyone
>   with access to that port has full Docker access; so it is not
>   advisable on an open network.***

---

> With -H it is possible to make the Docker daemon to listen on a
>   specific IP and port. By default, it will listen on
>   `unix:///var/run/docker.sock` to allow only local connections by the
>   root user. You could set it to `0.0.0.0:2375` or a specific host IP to
>   give access to everybody, but that is not recommended because then it
>   is trivial for someone to gain root access to the host where the
>   daemon is running.
>
> Similarly, the Docker client can use `-H` to connect to a custom port.
>   The Docker client will default to connecting to
>   `unix:///var/run/docker.sock` on Linux, and `tcp://127.0.0.1:2376` on
>   Windows.
>
> -H accepts host and port assignment in the following format:
>
> `tcp://[host]:[port][path] or unix://path`

---

> You can use multiple -H, for example, if you want to listen on both
>   TCP and a Unix socket
>
> ```
> # Run docker in daemon mode
> $ sudo <path to>/dockerd -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock &
> # Download an ubuntu image, use default Unix socket
> $ docker pull ubuntu
> # OR use the TCP port
> $ docker -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 pull ubuntu
> ```

Comment: I would recommend using a non ssh option, as passing environment variables like jenkins credentials is tricky (not impossible)

Comment: @MohammedRafeeq Tricky how?

Comment: from a jenkins file try passing a environment variable to the target docker machine  which is reached via ssh. you will understand what i mean

Comment: sh " DOCKER_HOST=\"${DOCKER_HOST}\" docker run -e ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE  ..."    is preferred. its easy to send the environment variable values, otherwise whatever  values are   set , they wont be accessible after ssh ing into the target docker host .DOCKER_HOSTvariable is of format tcp://hostname:2376    2376 is the default port

Answer (score 1):

As you said the connectivity is available between the servers, you can make use of Docker rich APIs.

There are 2 ways in configuring the docker daemon port

1) Configuring at **/etc/default/docker file**:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://127.0.0.1:5000 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
```

2) Configuring at **/etc/docker/daemon.json**:

```
{
"hosts": ["tcp://127.0.0.1:5000", "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"]
}
```

For more details on configuring docker daemon port, **[refer configure-docker-daemon-port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43699368/configure-docker-daemon-port-to-enable-docker-apis/43713435#43713435)**

Once the Docker ports are configured, you can access the Docker APIs in the remote host.

JSON input file:

```
#cat container_create.json 
{
  "AttachStdin": true,
  "AttachStdout": true,
  "AttachStderr": true,
  "ExposedPorts": {
    "property1": {},
    "property2": {}
  },
  "Tty": true,
  "OpenStdin": true,
  "StdinOnce": true,
  "Cmd": null,
  "Image": "ubuntu:14.04",
  "Volumes": {
    "additionalProperties": {}
  },
  "Labels": {
    "property1": "string",
    "property2": "string"
  }
}
```

**API to create a container:**

```
curl -X POST http://192.168.56.101:6000/containers/create -d @container_create.json --header "Content-Type: application/json" | jq .
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   602  100    90  100   512   1737   9883 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 10039
{
  "Warnings": null,
  "Id": "f5d3273e48350d606bd8b9d2a5bd876dc5c2d1a73183f876a1dd56473cad8940"
}
```

The ID generated is the container ID and status will not be active/running.

**API for starting the created container.**

```
# curl -X POST http://192.168.56.101:6000/containers/f5d3273e48350/start | jq .  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
```

**API to check the status/inspect the container:**

```
# curl -X GET http://192.168.56.101:6000/containers/f5d3273e48350/json | jq .
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  4076    0  4076    0     0   278k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  306k
{
  "NetworkSettings": {
    "Networks": {
      "bridge": {
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "IPAMConfig": null,
        "Links": null,
        "Aliases": null,
        "NetworkID": "689d6b65ce1b06c93b2c70f41760a3e7fb2b50697d71cd9c1f39c64c865e5fa6",
        "EndpointID": "76bf1f8638d1ff0387e6c3fe89e8ccab1670c709ad550f9acc6f46e559654bee",
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16
      }
    },
    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
    "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
    "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/24a031d9dfda",
    "Ports": {
      "0/tcp": null
    },
    "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
    "HairpinMode": false,
    "SandboxID": "24a031d9dfda70026a875f4841269c5e790b12ccafcc11869111faa240020b99",
    "Bridge": "",
    "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
    "EndpointID": "76bf1f8638d1ff0387e6c3fe89e8ccab1670c709ad550f9acc6f46e559654bee",
    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
    "IPv6Gateway": ""
  },

    },
    "AttachStderr": true,
    "AttachStdout": true,
    "AttachStdin": true,
    "User": "",
    "Domainname": "",
    "Hostname": "f5d3273e4835",
    "OpenStdin": true,
    "StdinOnce": true,
    "Env": [
      "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
    ],
    "Cmd": [
      "/bin/bash"
    ],
    "ArgsEscaped": true,
    "Image": "ubuntu:14.04",

<*************REMOVING THE OUTPUT CONTENT********>

  "ExecIDs": null,
  "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/f5d3273e48350d606bd8b9d2a5bd876dc5c2d1a73183f876a1dd56473cad8940/hostname",
  "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/f5d3273e48350d606bd8b9d2a5bd876dc5c2d1a73183f876a1dd56473cad8940/resolv.conf",
  "Image": "sha256:132b7427a3b40f958aaeae8716e0cbb2177658d2410554ed142e583ef522309f",
  "State": {
    "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "StartedAt": "2017-06-09T06:53:45.120357144Z",
    "Error": "",
    "Status": "running",
    "Running": true,
    "Paused": false,
    "Restarting": false,

  "Path": "/bin/bash",
  "Created": "2017-06-09T06:52:51.820429355Z",
  "Id": "f5d3273e48350d606bd8b9d2a5bd876dc5c2d1a73183f876a1dd56473cad8940",
  "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/f5d3273e48350d606bd8b9d2a5bd876dc5c2d1a73183f876a1dd56473cad8940/hosts",
  "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/f5d3273e48350d606bd8b9d2a5bd876dc5c2d1a73183f876a1dd56473cad8940/f5d3273e48350d606bd8b9d2a5bd876dc5c2d1a73183f876a1dd56473cad8940-json.log",
  "Name": "/objective_bartik",
  "RestartCount": 0,
  "Driver": "aufs",
  "MountLabel": "",
  "ProcessLabel": "",
  "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default"
}
```

Refer this for more info:

[DOCKER APIs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.28/)

**[How to build an Image using Docker API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43800339/how-to-build-an-image-using-docker-api)**

**[How to commit Docker Container using API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027873/how-to-create-a-new-docker-image-from-a-running-container-on-amazon/44374377#44374377)**

Hope this info will he helpful.

Comment: I've been using the `docker-py` API to test and tried to run the container on the machine B using `DOCKER_HOST`, unfortunately this ends up in the same result as calling `DOCKER_HOST=... docker run...`. Anyway, your solution seems to do what I'm looking for, I'll try it if `docker-machine` isn't working as expected. Thanks!

Comment: can you update for appropriate answer which has helped you.. it will help others as well when they face similar issue..Thanks..