# How to install only Docker client on MacOS?

Tags: macos, docker

Docker can work decently remotely by defining DOCKER_HOST variable but now I do want to avoid installing the fat Docker for MacOS which also installs and starts the docker engine on a VM, one that seems to consume resources.

As docker work remotely it should continue to be able to build images, list images, start and stop them without having a docker servic/vm mac.

How can I do this? (`docker` cli seems to be come only with the entire cow).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\`docker run\` on a remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446472/docker-run-on-a-remote-host)

Answer (score 5):

I guess you are looking for [install-client-binaries-on-macos](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/binaries/#install-client-binaries-on-macos).

Docker company afford some prebuilt binary, just download [here](https://download.docker.com/mac/static/stable/x86_64/), unpackage it, then you will find a standalone `docker client binary` there, copy it to your mac, out of the box for use.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no install of the client only; but after installing the fat cow, you can tell it to stay off your grass by unchecking *Start Docker Desktop when you log in* in the preferences, and then shut down the Docker server.

That's what I do, and when I need docker locally I just start and then after using it, I shut it down again.

Comment: I was hoping to find a better grazing solution. I will wait bit more before accepting it that workaround. Thanks!