# How do I configure Docker Desktop on Windows 10 to control another docker installation on a Debian computer

Tags: debian, docker-desktop, wsl-2

I have a Windows 10(Home) computer installed with WSL 2 and several docker containers running on it. I also have another computer on the same network installed with Debian 10.

How do I configure my Windows 10 Docker Desktop to Control/monitor Debian installation as well ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\`docker run\` on a remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446472/docker-run-on-a-remote-host).  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53252524/11810933) for the best way to do it on recent Docker releases.  Confirmed to work on WSL2/Docker Desktop.

Comment: My requirement is to Monitor / control all running docker containers at a glimpse regardless of the server(s) they are running. Although what you suggested is very useful  it does not do what I need.. Thank you

Comment: Ah, you want to see multiple remote/local hosts in the *GUI*?  I don't think that's going to be possible, but I could be wrong.  Most likely you'd need a third-party monitoring system for that.